# Extending a index block in shopware 6

Tags: shopware

When i try extending index page ,theme extend base layout(base.html.twig) of storefront not of plugin.
How i can extending index page with my custom base layout of plugin in the Shopware 6 ?

top of index.html.twig  i try use my namespace plugin

```
 {% sw_extends '@AKSoftware/storefront/base.html.twig' %}
```

but again extend base layout of storefront

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override blocks which are defined by plugins inside your custom theme as long as the order is defined correctly in your `theme.json`:

```
...

"views": [
  "@Storefront",
  "@Plugins",
  "@MyCustomTheme"
],

...
```

In general the process of overwriting template files is the same inside a plugin as it is inside a theme.